# Sum Amount, display full resultset where Groups of Column Values Match in Same Table Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I need to get the sum of all TOTAL fields where the ID, RECNO and DRCR fields have the same value, while also displaying these fields in the result set. 
eg

```
ID     RECNO      SECRECNO    DRCR    TOTAL
 1        9         5           D       25
 1        9         12          D       22
 1        9         6           C       33
 1        9         5           D       50
 1        8         2           D       12
 1        8         2           C       23
 2        9         5           D       100
```

So the results of the query should be

```
ID     RECNO      SECRECNO    DRCR    SUM(TOTAL)
 1       9           5         D        75
 1       9           12        D        22
 1       9           6         C        33
 1       8           2         D        12
 1       8           2         C        23
 2       9           5         D        100
```

This query will give the results set, without the TOTAL:

```
select distinct t1.recno, t1.secrecno
from table t1, table t2
where t1.recno = t2.recno and t.id = '1' and t1.drcr = 'D'
```

But I can't see how to SUM the TOTAL of these results. 
How to do this?

Comment: You have to `GROUP BY  ID, RECNO, DRCR`.

Comment: BTW: You are using a join syntax out-dated long ago. See MT0's answer on how to join properly.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos - that worked

Comment: Which column is in which table? Your join looks dubious, as you don't join by one of the tables' IDs. So with two records each in both tables for recno 1, you'd produce four result records (which you condense with DISTINCT to 1, 2, 3 or 4 result records depending on the values). You are likely to get your totals multiplied.

Comment: @Thorsten Thanks - that explains why my totals were so far off.

Comment: Is ID a text column or why do you compare it with the string '1' instead of the number 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.id,
       t1.recno,
       t1.secrecno,
       t1.drcr,
       SUM( TOTAL )
from   table t1
       INNER JOIN
       table t2
       ON ( t1.recno = t2.recno )
WHERE  t1.id = '1'
AND    t1.drcr = 'D' 
GROUP BY
       t1.id,
       t1.recno,
       t1.secrecno,
       t1.drcr
```